# Linq Query with Foreach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have a collection of policies that contain a collection of summaries that contain a serviceName and product type that can have comma separated  products.  I need to find if any of the policy summary serviceNames matches with any of comma separated values in the product type.  For example:

```
 productType.Split(',')
            .Select(p => p.Equals(policies.summaries.ForEach( s => { s.serviceName = p})));
```

and

```
var name = from s in productType.Split(',')
           where s = policies.summaries.ForEach(p=> { p.serviceName == s})
           select s;
```

I know the above wont compile but just wondered if it can be done in linq

Comment: You're currently *modifying* the summaries in the lambda expression in the first snippet. That's not the same as *checking* for them. Remember that LINQ is for *queries* - and be very clear about the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: Thanks John for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, try something like that:

```
var productTypes = productType.Split(',');

//if you need to get matched policies
var matchedPolicies = policies
    .Where(x => x.summaries.Any(y => productTypes.Contains(y.serviceName)));

//if you need to get matched summaries
var matchedSummaries = policies.SelectMany(x => x.summaries)
    .Where(x => productTypes.Contains(x.serviceName));
```

And then you can use `matchedPolicies.Any()` or `matchedSummaries.Any()` to determine if any of the policy summary serviceNames matches with any of comma separated values in the product type.

Alternatively if you don't care about concrete matched policies you can use `Any` right away `policies.Any(x => x.summaries.Any(y => productTypes.Contains(y.serviceName)))`

Also suggest [101 LINQ SAMPLES](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) for additional reading with some great examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
productType.Split(',').Any(x => policies.SelectMany(p => p.summaries)
                                        .Any(s => s.serviceName == x))
```

alternatively (faster, but less readable):

```
productType.Split(',').Join(policies.SelectMany(p => p.summaries),
                            x => x,              //match split strings
                            p => p.serviceName,  //with summary service name
                            (x, p) => p)         //selector - irrelevant with any
                      .Any()
```

Comment: You cant use **policies.summaries** should be **policies.SelectMany(x => x.summaries)**

Comment: How did you infer that from OP's code? In fact, on the contrary, I see him/her explicitly using `policies.summaries`, so two options - either it's a weird naming convention (I went with that), or OP's code samples are completely out of sync with reality - but good lack providing a meaningful answer in that case.

Comment: **"I have a collection of policies.."**

Comment: And he said that **"I know the above wont compile.."**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var query = from p in policies
                        from s in p.Summaries.Where(x => x.ProductType.Split(',').Contains(x.ServiceName))
                        select s.ServiceName;
```

Where I have used follwoing Type:-

```
 public class Summary
    {
        public string ServiceName {get; set;}
        public string ProductType {get; set;}
    }

    public class Policy
    {
        public List<Summary> Summaries { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is complete working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iY06p3).